# What are the names of these X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

Recently while re-watching *Deadpool 2* I realized how blatantly unaware I am of any of the names of X-Men especially in this scene.

Could somebody name these X-Men for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left to right, using the frame at 7 seconds, I see Cyclops (Tye Sheridan), Storm (Alexandra Shipp), Nightcrawler (Kodi Smit-McPhee), Beast (Nicholas Hoult), Quicksilver (Evan Peters), Professor X - aka Charles Xavier (James McAvoy.)

See: [This Link](https://www.inverse.com/article/45008-deadpool-2-x-men-cameo-easter-egg-marvel-movies) (where I snagged the actor names) for some addition info.